# Upper bound on a sum similar to a telescoping sum: $|p_{n'}-p_0| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n'}{|p_{i}-p_{i-1}|}$

Tags: inequality, summation

Does someone know why the following is true:

$$|p_{n'}-p_0| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n'}{|p_{i}-p_{i-1}|}$$

If we did not have the "size of" operator, there would be an equality, but in this case its a little different.

I was trying to prove that inequality but was not sure how. The triangle inequality seemed promising but was not sure how to start it since these quantities doesn't involve vectors and it involves sums of differences.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a standard trick to note that

$$|a - b| = |(a - c) - (b - c)| \le |a - c| + |b - c|$$

according to the triangle inequality. Now induct to prove the result for telescoping sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is multiple applications of the triangle inequality: $|x-z|\le|x-y|+|y-z|$. The triangle inequality is valid in one dimension as well as multiple dimensions.
$$
\begin{align}
|p_n-p_0|
&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^np_i-p_{i-1}\right|\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^n|p_i-p_{i-1}|
\end{align}
$$